# How can we import files from PC directly in SAS University Edition?

Tags: sas, sas-studio

I am using SAS University Edition and i have to import files into SAS software. I have tried using 'infile' and 'proc import' statements but these are not working when accessing the files directly from PC.

Is there a way to access the files directly from PC in SAS UE?

Comment: Step by Step instructions in the post on July 6th by Cynthia Zender: https://communities.sas.com/message/218581#218581. If you look at the left hand side of the screen there are a lot of similar questions that you can also refer to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

1. In the folder where you have SAS University Edition VM located
   created a folder called **myfolders**.
2. In the VM create a shared folder to that folder using the VM
   settingsn th
3. Move the file to that location and use a UNIX path that is case sensitive to refer to the file in your infile statement.

There are other ways but this is the simplest to start off with.

Detailed instructions vary slightly based on your OS (MAC/PC) and VM(ORACLE/VMWARE).  Please see the SAS Analytics Help Centre FAQ
http://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/main.htm
and here:
https://communities.sas.com/docs/DOC-7211