# physical file does not exists while using sas studio

Tags: sas

I am new to sas. I downloaded and installed the university version from here: http://www.sas.com/en_us/software/university-edition.html
Now, I am learning it with the book "learning sas by examples". https://www.sas.com/storefront/aux/en/splearnexample/60864_excerpt.pdf
The code is very simple:

```
data veg;
    infile "D:\sas\veggies.txt";
    input Name $ Code $ Days Number Price;
    CostPerSeed = Price/Number;
run;
```

The header of the file veggies file is as the following:

```
cucumber 50104-A 55 30 195
cucumber 51789-A 56 30 225
Carrot 50179-A 68 1500 395
```

I do not understand why. Could anyone help me with it please? Many many thanks.

EDIT: After constant trying, it seems like the shared folder works, but the code still does not work. The code is as the following:

```
data veg;
   infile "C:\mydownloadedsoftware\unvbasicvapp_9411005_vmx_en_sp0_1(1)\SAS-University-Edition\myfolders\smile.txt";
   input Name $ Code $ Days Number Price;

   CostPerSeed = Price/Number;

run;
```

The smile.txt is as the following:

```
Cucumber 50104-A  55 30 195
Cucumber 51789-A  56 30 225
```

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please read the installation instructions step by step. You need to set up a shared drive and then move the file to the shared drive and reference there.

Comment: @Reeza, many thanks for your reply. I am running it locally not in the server, so I still need to set up a shared drive?

Comment: Yes, because its running on a VM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28428264/1919583

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we import files from PC directly in SAS University Edition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426511/how-can-we-import-files-from-pc-directly-in-sas-university-edition)

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind comments. It took me a long time and I was still confused though. Based on the link http://www.sas.com/en_us/software/university-edition.html, it seems like that I can put the myfolder folder wherever I want. But the link Reeza provided said that it needs to be put in the location where SAS university VM located. I tried both, but still it does not work. Could someone help me with it? Many many thanks.

Comment: What part doesnt work? Setting up shared folder? Accessing data. Explain step by step what you did and include a screenshot of your shared folder in SAS UE.

Comment: I do not know which part. I followed exactly as the link sas.com/en_us/software/university-edition.html, it still gets physical file does not exist. I followed the other solution to put the folder in a specific location, and I still got the same physical file does  not exist error. One question, how to know that the shared folder has been set up successflly

Comment: When you start up SAS UE it checks for updates (orange screen) then if shared folder isnt set up properly it shows an note to that effect. If you cant list step by step with screen shots I cant help beyond the original instructions already posted.

Comment: Many thanks, Reeza. This just drive me crazy. You mean, when you type the address in your local explorer? When I enter the URL,  I got the "A shared folder named "mayfolders" was not found on your virtual machine. See the FAQ for details."

Comment: On the left of the SAS studio, there are server files and folders pane, under which there are folder shortcuts and my folders two options. During my continuous trying, there are times where the file I intended to use for data analysis, say mydata.txt, appears under the folder shortcuts and there are also times where mydata.txt appears under the my folders option. Which one should it be ?

Comment: @Reeza, many thanks for your time and attention. Here is what I did.

Comment: (1): open the folder where the VMware virtual machine configuration exists, and create a folder with name myfolders. Put the file mydata.txt there.

Comment: (2): open the VMware, right click on the vapp and choose settings.

Comment: (3): Choose options, and choose shared folders, and enable it. Add the path to the myfolders created earlier.

Comment: (4): open the vmware and open the sas vapp.

Comment: You should modify the question, not post in the comments. When you open SAS UE does it say that the myfolders is created properly? Can you see it under myfolders? What code did you submit that doesn't work?

Comment: Could someone help me please? Or do I need to download and restart from the very beginning ?

Comment: @Reeza, when I open the URL http://192.168.81.128, under the notifications, it told me " A shared folder named "myfolders" was not found on the virtual machine. See the FAQ for details". When I click the "Start SAS studio", in the sas studio, I can find medata.txt under folder shortcuts, not under my folders.

Comment: Try readding your shared folder. Restart the VM. The shared folder has to be exactly named myfolders all lower case and under the SAS UE folder. Otherwise contact sasanalyticsu@sas.com for tech support.

Comment: @Reeza, the SAS UE folder is the same as the folder where the VMware virtual machine configuration exists, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You should have a folder called SAS-UniversityEdition that you download. Put it in there.

Comment: @Reeza, this totally drives me crazy. I just tried again. This time, it seems like the shared file works. But I still get the physical file does not exist error !!!

Comment: Your code is most likely wrong. Post it - in the question not comments.

Comment: Your code is wrong. See Cynthia's answer here. https://communities.sas.com/message/218581#218581.

Comment: infile "/folders/myfolders/smile.txt";

Comment: I'm going to assume it worked?

Comment: Yes. it works. Sorry for being late reply. Thanks, Reeza.