# Importing XLSX file into SAS

Tags: excel, sas

```
OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;

  PROC IMPORT OUT= Census.taxp_lookupDATAFILE="C:\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
                     DBMS=xlsx REPLACE;
               SHEET="tax_group";
               GETNAMES=YES;
          RUN;

 ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /opt/sasinside/SASConfig/Lev1/SASApp/C:\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\/Book1.xlsx.
```

I am facing this error while importing excel file into sas. What do i need to change in my code

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/ERROR-Physical-file-does-not-exist-opt-sasinside-SASConfig-Lev1/td-p/147659

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28426511/1919583

Answer (score 0):

> you basically need to specify the data to be read: DATAFILE=""

```
/** Import an XLSX file.  **/

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="<Your XLSX File>"
        OUT=WORK.MYEXCEL
        DBMS=XLSX
        REPLACE;
RUN;

/** Print the results. **/

PROC PRINT DATA=WORK.MYEXCEL; RUN;
```

[image: here is how to find the right path for your folder]

[Video on how to find the excel file and find the right path for SASstudio](http://www.sas.com/apps/webnet/video-sharing.html?player=brightcove&width=640&height=360&autoStart=true&playerID=1873162645001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABs_kuvqE~,9q03viSCCi8Qu-ec7KH7e-bapzBTKVDB&videoPlayer=4262543790001&emptyPage=false)

> PS: to answer the questions: "basically you need to have the file already in My Folders and not path to your local desktop file, also if you are using a server than you need to import, I'm not sure if to SAS University Edition is the option Import on right click folder like in picture listed below: Screen for import is SAS Studio"

[image: Screen for import in SAS Studio]